# HELP - problem setting up Linux FW with two interfaces

Tags: networking, iptables, docker, routing, container

First of all, sorry about my English lul

I have a pretty simple infrastructure running under **docker**:

`container1`: iptables firewall;

`container2`: https repository;

`container3`: ansible server.

***container1*** has two interfaces so it can goes out trought WAN via **eth0** and communicate with containers 2 and 3 via **eth1** (LAN).

**The problem** im facing is to make LAN able to reach the internet (ping -c3 google.com).

`container1` - I've already set ipv4_forwarding and made WAN's GW my default route (it communicates with the other two containers and reaches the internet).

`container2`; `container3` - they communicate normally on LAN but just can't ping FW's IP addr so don't reach the WAN... I've set a static route spreading FW's WAN subnet and now they can ping *200.200.100.1* (docker's bridged interface which is used as FW subnet GW, FW IP: *200.200.200.2*).

Am I missing any iptables conf (didn't make nothing yet) or do I need to configure a route out of the docker (between interfaces docker0-docker1 on host machine)?

Can send container routing tables if you need it, maybe there's something missing.

Hope some buddy could give me a hand ")

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the LAN subnet is **10.20.20.0/24** (docker IP range) and the interface to the internet (WAN) is **eth0**

Execute the following commands on the host machine where docker bridge is (your host machine will act as a firewall in this case)

```
# apt install iptables-persistent -y
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -d 10.20.20.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
# iptables -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT
# netfilter-persistent save
# netfilter-persistent reload
```

Comment: Bruce, same thing even after doing this... don't know if the problem is the container acting as fw or any network issue on my local machine... don't we need to configure iptables outside docker too?

Comment: In my example, 10.20.20.0/24 is the IP range that docker containers are using. The iptables commands will be executed on the host machine.

Comment: works fine ;]             thanks a lot bruvahhh